# Achieving pass by reference in C with pointer to pointer?

Tags: pass-by-reference

So I just finished reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) and realized that Java is actually entirely pass-by-value.  In one of the answers it noted some languages are pass by reference, but C and Java are not.  Since I am mostly familiar with C and Java and not familiar with the languages listed as languages which support pass by reference, I suppose it's possible that I've never seen pass by reference.  My question is whether passing a pointer to a pointer to an object as a parameter in C and then modifying what the pointer to the object points to is essentially achieving pass-by-reference.

*Example:*
If I have a pointer `bar` and wanted to "pass it by reference" so I could change the object it points to, I could pass a pointer to bar which we can call `foo`. `foo` would be passed to the function by value, but we could change the value `bar` points to within that function.  Is that essentially pass by reference from bar's perspective?  Or does pass by reference work differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing by reference is not only different from passing by value. It's also different from "passing by pointer", i. e. passing a pointer to an object by value.

However, you are correctly assuming that one can emulate passing by reference using pointers. Namely, if you have an object of type `T`, and you pass a pointer of type `T *` as a function argument that points to that object, then the function can modify the object. Something like this:

```
void change(int *n)
{
    *n = 1337;
}

int i = 42;
printf("Before: %d\n", i); /* prints 42 */
change(&i);
printf("After: %d\n", i);  /* prints 1337 */
```

That's why reference types are often implemented using pointers in some languages, but conceptually (and often syntactically and in some semantical details as well) they are different.

Comment: Can you elaborate on / give an example of what true passing by reference looks like?

Comment: @Kvass For example, in C++, you can declare a reference type using the `&` qualifier. Like this: `void change(int &n) { n = 1337; }` - then (syntactically) you don't pass the address of the variable, but "the variable itself". I don't know about other languages, though.